# How to get func documentation in golang?

Tags: go

How can I get the func description within go code?

```
// My very nice description
func myFunc() { ... }
```

I'd like to have `My very nice description`.

Getting the name of a func is pretty straight forward:

```
runtime.FuncForPC(reflect.ValueOf(myFunc).Pointer()).Name()
```

Is there something similar for the documentation? It would be ok for me to parse the original go file. Any shortcuts there?

Comment: What you're looking for is not possible; documentation is not included in the compiled output.

Comment: Not at runtime within your app (comments aren't included in the binary), but there's always `go doc` while you're working.

Comment: It would be ok for me to parse the file and read it. Any shortcut functions available for that? I‘m currently fiddling around with go/ast but it‘s kinda tricky. I was thinking that there may be an easier solution?

Comment: Use the [go/doc](https://godoc.org/go/doc) package to extract documentation from source code.

Comment: Uhm... i‘m kinda puzzled that i haven‘t found THAT one. Thanks.

Comment: `go doc` command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [go/doc](https://godoc.org/go/doc) package to extract documentation from source code.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case someone needs the code, I'll post it here. It may be a bit ugly still, but works fine for my scenarios. You may adjust it upon your own needs.

```
package funcreader

import (
    "go/ast"
    "go/doc"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
    "path/filepath"
    "reflect"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)

// Get the name and path of a func
func FuncPathAndName(f interface{}) string {
    return runtime.FuncForPC(reflect.ValueOf(f).Pointer()).Name()
}

// Get the name of a func (with package path)
func FuncName(f interface{}) string {
    splitFuncName := strings.Split(FuncPathAndName(f), ".")
    return splitFuncName[len(splitFuncName)-1]
}

// Get description of a func
func FuncDescription(f interface{}) string {
    fileName, _ := runtime.FuncForPC(reflect.ValueOf(f).Pointer()).FileLine(0)
    funcName := FuncName(f)
    fset := token.NewFileSet()

    // Parse src
    parsedAst, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, fileName, nil, parser.ParseComments)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return ""
    }

    pkg := &ast.Package{
        Name:  "Any",
        Files: make(map[string]*ast.File),
    }
    pkg.Files[fileName] = parsedAst

    importPath, _ := filepath.Abs("/")
    myDoc := doc.New(pkg, importPath, doc.AllDecls)
    for _, theFunc := range myDoc.Funcs {
        if theFunc.Name == funcName {
            return theFunc.Doc
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the godoc tool to generate documentation.

Check the following link
https://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code

It should give what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks. I was actually looking for go/doc which receives the AST and delivers a shortcut for getting func docs.

Comment: This is a link-only answer - if the link dies, the answer contains no useful information. See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/284827) or [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/284827) for more information.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Agreed and changed